# Preservation of human tissue

Tags: biochemistry

At my med school we have human samples (body parts, organs, etc.)

They are soaked in some sort of solution for long term storage. I'm quite sure that it's not formaldehyde as that would be really toxic and we're allowed to pick them up from the tubs.

What sort of solution could this be?

Comment: I would assume you're using gloves to handle them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Embalming solutions for cadaver study differ from institution to institution (and are reportedly somewhat different from embalming for funerals, but I'm not sure of those details). Typically embalming solutions for cadavers meant to be stored indefinitely consist mostly of water with lesser but roughly equal amounts alcohol (usually methanol), gylcerin, phenol, and a smaller percentage of formalin/formaldehyde to prevent mold.

[A document from Albert Einstein College of Medicine](https://www.einstein.yu.edu/administration/environmental-health-safety/training/anatomy-students.aspx) lists:

- Methanol: 11.1%
- Glycerin: 11.1%
- Phenol: 9.3%
- Formaldehyde: 1.9%

If you want to know what your institution uses, you should just ask, and they should be willing and able to tell you.

Comment: Thank you. That explains why it's okay for us to handle them.